# Auto read OTP from SMS for Hybrid app with Ionic 3

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a hybrid App build with Ionic 3, in which server sends an SMS with the OTP and the user needs to enter this OTP in the App. How the App should be able to automatically read the OTP sent by the server. How can I achieve this?

Any help or guidance in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: on iOS you need to set the text field content type to "One time password"; iOS will then offer any code received as an autofill - I am not sure if it is possible to do this in a hybrid app, it may only be exposed via native code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms-receive

You can startWatch() once the OTP is sent, and read the body of the message to find the exact position of the OTP numbers.